# Reload UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, reload

I have a class implementing the `UITableViewDelegate` and the `NSXMLParserDelegate`. My app is tab based. When I select the proper tab, in the `viewWillAppear` method of my class I start my xml parser to parse the rss feed at a specific url, then I populate my `UITableView` with the contents of the feeds.
Now I want to have a button to "refresh" the view (that is parse the rss feed again and display the new results). So, I have this method given as the action of the refresh button:

```
-(IBAction)refreshFeeds:(id)sender
{
    if (stories){
        [stories release];  // Stories is an NSMutableArray for storing the parsed feeds
        stories = nil;
    }
    [self viewWillAppear:YES];
    NSLog(@"RELOADING!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
}
```

My problem is that when i press the "refresh" button the view turns to blank, as if there are no feeds to display.
If then i switch to another tab an then come back, the tableview populates again with the feeds.
What am i doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

(Here is part of how i implemented the class)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if ([stories count] == 0){
        NSString * path = @"http://www.theRssUrl.com";
        [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
    }
}
//custom method to parse rss xml
- (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL {

    if (stories) {
        [stories release];
        stories = nil;
    }
    stories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];
    //you must then convert the path to a proper NSURL or it won't work
    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];

    rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
    [rssParser setDelegate:self];

    [rssParser parse];
}
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser { 

    [newsTable reloadData]; //newsTable is the UITableView i want to refresh
    self.view = newsTable;
    [rssParser release];
    rssParser = nil;
}
```

EDIT:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   // Configure the cell.
   static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    int storyIndex = indexPath.row;

    cell.lTitle.text = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];
    cell.lSummary.text = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"summary"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Don't call `[super viewDidAppear:animated];` in `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` call `[super viewWillAppear:animated];`.

Comment: Hello @Nick thank you for replying. The first is just a type error i made writing the question, actually it's [super viewWillAppear:animated]; As for your second comments, in the refreshFeeds method i empty the stories array, so the count should be 0 - am i missing something here?

Comment: @CrisDeBlonde You can call `[self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];` directly to refresh your feed as this method empties the array. Don't call viewWillAppear directly. Just call parseXMLFileAtURL in viewWillAppear and refreshFeeds.

Comment: @CrisDeBlonde I am thin that this `self.view = newsTable;` is not correct if you are in a viewController. You should add your tableView in loadView or with a nib file to your view controller and then just call `[tableView reloadData]` in the parserDidEndDocument.

Comment: @Nick i have already tried calling `[self parseXMLFileAtURL:path]; `instead of viewWillAppear, the result is the same.  
I'm not sure i understand your last comment, could you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: @CrisDeBlonde The code is in a viewController, right? And my sentence was just bad english. It has to be "I thinl that this self.view = newsTable; is not correct...". All the delegate and datascource method for the tableView are in this viewController? If yes, then using reloadData should just update the tableView if stories is filled with data. Can you show us how you setup the tableView?

Comment: @pratikshabhisikar @Nick ok, i think i'm a bit confused now :P
To set up the table view i use the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method (I'll update my answer with it in a few secs).  
I used  `self.view = newsTable` so that the newsTable becomes the current view - so that it's contents can be displayed.

Comment: can you make sure your parserDidEndDocument and other parser delegates are getting called on button press. Also try skipping self.view = newsTable statement

Comment: @pratikshabhisikar all parser delegate methods are getting called. If i skip the `self.view = newsTable` statement then the newsTable is not displayed and all i get is an empty view...

Comment: @CrisDeBlonde is your view loaded from a nib file or how do you create the tableView? If not from a nib can you show us the code where you create it?

Comment: @Nick my view is loaded from a nib file, i do not create it programmatically.

Comment: @Nick At last i made it! I had a stupid mistake with the tableView delegate, i fixed it and then followed your suggestion at your second comment and used parseXMLFileAtURL instead of viewWillLoad. Please make your comment a reply so i can accept it as the solution. Thank you very much for your time and your help!

Comment: @CrisDeBlonde good to hear! Here you go with an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `[self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];` directly to refresh your feed as this method empties the array. Don't call viewWillAppear directly. Just call parseXMLFileAtURL in viewWillAppear and refreshFeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Calling viewWillAppear explicity is incorrect. You should rather have the reload logic in a separate function, call that function in viewWillAppear and on button press. Calling viewWillAppear in button press is something i dont think is correct.

Comment: Hello @pratikshabhisikar  thanx for replying! Even if i call the [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path]; instead of viewWillAppear the result is the same...

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your code, `stories` is the array that is providing the data for the `newsTable`. You are nil-ing it and updating the array. What if the `newsTable` requests data from its data source in between. It will find that `stories` to be empty and hence will have no data to show. We can assume there will a small but significant amount of delay in downloading and parsing your rss data. During this time, `stories` will remain empty.

You should consider downloading the rss data and parsing it into a different array. Replace the `stories` just before you are ready to refresh `newsTable`.